# Positioning an element to inline element at the start

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my container, i am trying to position my `tooltip` to the `inline` element by dynamic. I am getting the position too..

the issue is, i would like to keep my `tooltip` at the start of the `text` (first letter of inline element) instead of the `left` what i am receiving from query.

now all works, but the `tooltip` not aligned to the `start` point of the `inline` element.

how do calculate the `left` position with `indexOf('firstLetter')' ?

here is my code :

```
var toolTip = '<div class="toolTip" id="toolTip">';
        toolTip += '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info saveText btn-xs copy">Save Text</a>';
        toolTip += '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info makeQuery btn-xs">Make Query</a></div>';

var getPosition = function (element) {
    var childPos = element.offset();
    return childOffset = {
        top: childPos.top ,
        left: childPos.left
    }
}

$('.yellow').on('click', function () {
    var yellow = $('.first');
    var position = getPosition(yellow);
    $('#container').append($(toolTip).css({top:position.top,left:position.left}));
});

$('.green').on('click', function () {
    var green = $('.second');
    var position = getPosition(green);
    $('#container').append($(toolTip).css({top:position.top,left:position.left}));
});

$('.blue').on('click', function () {
    var blue = $('.third');
    var position = getPosition(blue);
    $('#container').append($(toolTip).css({top:position.top,left:position.left}));
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7qywy6f/3/)

Comment: For a start, have a look at this: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `position:relative` for each `span` classes. This is better way to locate the toolTip text

```
.first, .second, .third { position:relative }
```

and `#toolTip` css `top` position is `-35px` to prevent the toolTip blocking the text.

```
#toolTip { top:-35px }
```

also more simple jQuery here

```
var toolTip = '<div class="toolTip" id="toolTip">';
        toolTip += '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info saveText btn-xs copy">Save Text</a>';
        toolTip += '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info makeQuery btn-xs">Make Query</a></div>';

$('.yellow').on('click', function () {
    $('.first').find('div').first().remove(); // remove existing toolTip
    $('.first').append(toolTip);
    $('.second').find('div').first().remove();
    $('.third').find('div').first().remove();
});

$('.green').on('click', function () {
    $('.second').find('div').first().remove();
    $('.second').append(toolTip);
    $('.first').find('div').first().remove();
    $('.third').find('div').first().remove();
});

$('.blue').on('click', function () {
    $('.third').find('div').first().remove();
    $('.third').append(toolTip);
    $('.first').find('div').first().remove();
    $('.second').find('div').first().remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7qywy6f/5/

Comment: Yes, I agree, but when i click on `yellow` the first button, the tooltip moves out of boundary (`#container`) if that's the case how to adjust the left, right, top or bottom - whenever the `tooltip` move out of the parent? ( i don't what to move the tooltip to go out of container, instead let it adjust the position.

Comment: You can see `.first` is `position:relative` and `#toolTip` is `position:absolute`. Position **relative** mean it will be the element's parent, and position **absolute** is the child of it. So, you just have to set the `position:absolute` in this case `#toolTip`, change the `top` and `left` style, I write there `top:-35px`, change it to `top:20px` to keep `#toolTip` inside the text